# mutate a column conditionally in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

with a df like below, using dplyr I need to mutate the fields val1, val2, val3 conditionally.

```
> df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2), 
  loc=c("loc1", "loc2"), 
  val1=c(80,64), val2=c(240,32768), val3=c(32768, 64)
)
> df
  id  loc val1  val2  val3
1  1 loc1   80   240 32768
2  2 loc2   64 32768    64
```

I need set the values in `val1, val2, val3` to `NA` if the value is > 1000

```
df %>%
 mutuate_at(vars(starts_with("v")), <what goes here>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need `mutate_at` with `replace`

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("v")), funs(replace(., .>1000, NA)))
#    id  loc val1 val2 val3
#1  1 loc1   80  240   NA
#2  2 loc2   64   NA   64
```

Comment: what does the . (dot) notation mean inside the replace function ?

Comment: @user3206440  The `.` denotes each column

Comment: could you pls add a document reference for this .

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in a nontidy format. Tidy it up with `gather` before mutating:

```
library(tidyverse)
 df %>% 
  gather("key", "val", val1, val2, val3) %>%
  mutate(val = ifelse(val > 1000, NA, val))
```

If you want to then return you dataframe to its original, nontidy, format, you can use `spread`

```
df %>%
  spread(key, val)
```